# Different results with and without primary key column in select statement. Why?

Tags: sql, union

I have a Query which returns two different results when I have the Primary Key in the select list and an another result when primary key is not there.

Given below is the query with primary key 'FDReciptNo'.

With Primary key the result is (3478) records, without primary key in the select statement in both inner select statement I have 1274 records.

Want to understand why there is such a difference?

```
SELECT SUM(PrincipleAmount) AS PrincipleAmount FROM
(
    SELECT  
            FDReceiptNo, PrincipleAmount
    FROM mFixedDeposit
    WHERE   CurrentStatus = ' ' AND 
            DepositDate <= '9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM' AND 
            FDReceiptNo NOT IN
            (
                SELECT FDReceiptNo FROM mFixedDeposit 
                WHERE 
                    TransactionDate > '9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM' AND MaturityDate <= '9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM'
            )

    UNION   
    SELECT  
            FDReceiptNo, PrincipleAmount
    FROM mFixedDeposit
    WHERE   TransactionDate > '9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM' AND 
            MaturityDate <= '9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM'

) AS tbl
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`UNION` also performs a `DISTINCT`, so if without the PK you have multiple occurences of the rest of the columns, these will be reduced to one.

Try `UNION ALL`, which doesn't imply `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

As [geomagas pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19259000/119477) there's an implicit DISTINCT with UNION, but since the same tables and fields are involved you can just use an `OR` instead. This also allows you to remove the inline view

```
SELECT
    SUM(PrincipleAmount) AS PrincipleAmount     
FROM mFixedDeposit
WHERE   (CurrentStatus = ' ' AND 
        DepositDate <= '9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM' AND 
        FDReceiptNo NOT IN
        (
            SELECT FDReceiptNo FROM mFixedDeposit 
            WHERE 
                TransactionDate > '9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM' AND MaturityDate <= '9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM'
        ))
        OR
        (
           TransactionDate > '9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM' AND 
           MaturityDate <= '9/20/2013 12:00:00 AM'
        )
```